# I have tailwind CSS and DaisyUI in my next.js project but I can't seem to have get my font to go bold

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, daisyui

Earlier i had installed and uninstalled font awesome from my project because I think It was getting some errors on the babel configs so i deleted those files I have made but. Right now I tried to bold some texts but it wont seem to work. I was wondering if anyone had the same experiences as I do.

The specific ones I was talking about with the errors are my H1 in the hero component and the benefits component.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//globals.css

@import 'daisyui/dist/full.css';

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//index.js

import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Navbar from '../../components/navbar'
import Hero from '../../components/hero'
import Benefits from '../../components/benefits'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
    <Navbar/>
    <Hero/>
    <Benefits/>
    </>
  )
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//app.js

import '@/styles/globals.css'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//benefits.js

import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Benefits() {
  return (

    <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-4">
      <div>
        <p className="font-bold">Guaranteed Cooling</p>
        <p>using modern cleaning techniques, you can be assured top-notch ac cleaning</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p className="font-bold">Guaranteed Cooling</p>
        <p>using modern cleaning techniques, you can be assured top-notch ac cleaning</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p className="font-bold">Guaranteed Cooling</p>
        <p>using modern cleaning techniques, you can be assured top-notch ac cleaning</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p className="font-bold">Guaranteed Cooling</p>
        <p>using modern cleaning techniques, you can be assured top-notch ac cleaning</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//hero.js

import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Hero() {
  return (
    <div
      className="hero min-h-screen bg-base-200"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: "url('/aircon_background_hero.png')",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundPosition: "center",
      }}
    >
      <div className="hero-content flex-col lg:flex-row-reverse">
        <div>
          <Image
            src="/hero-image.png"
            alt="A thumbs up image"
            width={800}
            height={600}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="lg:w-1/2">
          {/* The div below will appear after the Image on mobile */}
          <div className="my-4 md:my-0">
            <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold">Box Office News!</h1>
            <p className="py-6">
              Provident cupiditate voluptatem et in. Quaerat fugiat ut assumenda
              excepturi exercitationem quasi. In deleniti eaque aut repudiandae et
              a id nisi.
            </p>
            <button className="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//tailwindconfig.js

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  themes: [
    {
      mytheme: {
      
"primary": "#2563eb",
      
"secondary": "#7c3aed",
      
"accent": "#f97316",
      
"neutral": "#2a323c",
      
"base-100": "#f3f4f6",
      
"info": "#3abff8",
      
"success": "#36d399",
      
"warning": "#fbbd23",
      
"error": "#f87272",
      },
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('daisyui'),
  ],
  daisyui: {
    themes: true, // true: all themes | false: only light + dark | array: specific themes like this ["light", "dark", "cupcake"]
    darkTheme: false, // name of one of the included themes for dark mode
    base: true, // applies background color and foreground color for root element by default
    styled: true, // include daisyUI colors and design decisions for all components
    utils: true, // adds responsive and modifier utility classes
    rtl: false, // rotate style direction from left-to-right to right-to-left. You also need to add dir="rtl" to your html tag and install `tailwindcss-flip` plugin for Tailwind CSS.
    prefix: "", // prefix for daisyUI classnames (components, modifiers and responsive class names. Not colors)
    logs: true, // Shows info about daisyUI version and used config in the console when building your CSS
  },
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not sure if I posted the problem correctly, please let me know if there are points I could improve on and I hope anyone else has experience with this problem.

Thank you very much

I have previously had downloaded fontAwesome which required me to add some babel configs but i deleted those because I decided not to go with fontAwesome to make things less complicated but I don't think that was the reason.

I have also inspected it in the browser and the bolded font seems to be working fine when i tick out the 'inherited' value.

Comment: Hi, I think you have used `next/fonts` for inter fonts you have initialized inter regular  font. You need to define fonts variant that you want like `bold`, `semibold` etc. Check this Nextjs official documentation this will guide you step by step. https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#specifying-a-subset